# Received memory warning when loading uibweview

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, uiwebview, didreceivememorywarning

I have a method that load some youtube videos in a UIWebview and i have lots of videos and when i am running the code i am getting **Received memory warning** and app get crashed. I tried to fix it using `did received memory waring` but its not working this is the method that i am using :-

```
-(void) setScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollview :(NSArray *)contentArray{

int x=0;

for(NSDictionary *str in contentArray){

    UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, 123, 123)];

    webView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    webView.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    NSString *link = [str objectForKey:@"UTUBEURL"];

    link = [@"http://www.youtube.com/v/" stringByAppendingFormat:link];

    NSLog(@"link = %@",link);


    NSString *embedHTML = @"\
    <html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0  \">\
    <style type=\"text/css\">\
    body {\
    background-color: transparent;\
    color: white;\
    }\
    </style>\
    </head><body width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" style=\"margin:0\">\
    <embed id=\"yt\" src=\"%@\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" \
    width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\" autostart=\"true\"></embed>\
    </body></html>";

    NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML,webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height,link, webView.frame.size.width, webView.frame.size.height];


    [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];


    UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,123,200,20)];

    [title setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:11]];
    [title setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [title setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    title.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[str objectForKey:@"DISPLAYTEXT"]];

    x += webView.frame.size.width+2;


    [scrollview addSubview:webView];
    [scrollview addSubview:title];

}

scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(x, scrollview.frame.size.height);
}
```

i am having about 50 videos here so what can i do to avoid this i am calling this method in side my **viewDidLoad**. Is there a way to do this better using a thread, can someone help me with this? but i dont have any knowledge on thread on ios.

Comment: Allocating alot of uiwebview is quite expensive

Comment: Why are you creating 50 Webviews??, Create a single WebView and replace the urls to be played on that WebView only, Is it something different from your requirement?

Comment: You can use swipe gesture to chnage Videos to be played on that Webview and according to it replace your UILabels too.

Comment: @mAc yah its different from my request , i want to add a set of video on my main screen and when user press the play button video should play, like a video gallery

Comment: create your own player control, but not the webview

Comment: you can avoid this memory warning by not loading all the video at the same time. First load 5-10 video then after that try to load video on requirement basic.

Comment: Is it a iPad app or iPhone?, You can do one thing, Make icons of videos to be played in a scrollview and put a hidden button over it, when user taps on the button, play the video in Using MPMoviePlayerController in a fullScreen window.

Comment: its Iphone app , i try to use MPMoviePlayerController but its not work  can you send me a good example for that its will be a great help

Comment: Hi, I have the same issue , do you solve it . Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not write the whole code for you, but giving you a short piece of code to help you.

You make a scrollView, having thumbnail images of what video to play and save the urls in an array respectively then

```
**In VideoPlayContoller.h**

#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
@interface VideoPlayViewController : UIViewController{

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController;

}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int i;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *allVideoUrls;

-(void)playVideo:(int)_index;

- (IBAction)onTapBack:(id)sender;

@end

**In VideoPlayContoller.m**

#import "VideoPlayViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@implementation VideoPlayViewController

@synthesize i,allVideoUrls;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        allVideoUrls = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [self playVideo:i];
}

-(void)playVideo:(int)_index{

    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[allVideoUrls objectAtIndex:i]];

    if(!moviePlayerController){
        moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:moviePlayerController];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(doneButtonClick:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
    }
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController setContentURL:fileURL];
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0){
        [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 62, 320, 504)];
    }
    else{
        [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 62, 320, 416)]; //y = 42
    }
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];

    [moviePlayerController play];   
}

- (IBAction)onTapBack:(id)sender {
    [moviePlayerController stop];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification{
    i++;

      [moviePlayerController stop];
      [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
      [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}

-(void)doneButtonClick:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    NSLog(@"Done button Clicked");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: thank you for ur answer @mAc, sorry for troubling you  but can you show me how to call this call this class ? i write a method to get the tap of a simple image and get the index number of it, but i am confuse how to call the class that you give me can you help me with that ! i am sorry to trouble you , i am bit new to ios programming

Comment: and one another thing i can not get the GAITrackedViewController to my project is there a additional lib that i have to use to get to it work  ? thank you

Comment: Use UIViewController instead of GAITrackedViewController

Comment: when you get the index of which image you clicked then just call the method playVideo from VideoPlayViewController object and pass the index to it like [myObjectOfVideoPlayViewController playVideo:_indexTapped];

Comment: thank you mac is there a specific format that i have to use when i give a youtube video link, i call the function with a link like this `http://www.youtube.com/v/xxxxx`  and when i debug and see what happen when it come to the point `[moviePlayerController play]; ` this shows in NSLog `oid SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:identifierForInitialRequest:fromDataSource:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode`

Comment: Thanx a lot bro i found a way to play youtube videos in here [Youtube Player](https://github.com/DpzAtMicRO/IOSYoutubePlayer) have to do some modifications but its work charm, THanks for your help. Without your help i can not go that far thanx again

Comment: cool :), you may accept the answer and close this Question if u want :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use a `UICollectionView` - whats happening is you are loading lots of these webviews into memory and its just too much. You need to take advantage of cell reuse.

Take a read of a few tutorials and get yourself upto speed -

1. http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12
2. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html
3. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UICollectionView
4. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/